# How do I split a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

In my test step, I need to split letters.

```
find(:xpath,"//*[]").text
```

gives a string like `"No#xyz1"`, where `No#` is a static part.

I need `xyz1`. How do I get that part?

Comment: Please post some efforts you made.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and the linked pages. You need to show evidence of your effort, and supply the minimum input that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) comes to the rescue:

```
"No#xyz1"[/(?<=No#).*/]
#⇒ "xyz1"
```

So in your matcher you can use:

```
find(:xpath,"//*[]").text[/(?<=No#).*/] == "xyz1"
```

Comment: Alternatively `text[/No#(.*)/, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that. You can, for example, use regular expression and scan method:

```
[1] pry(main)> "No#xyz1".scan(/No#(.+)/).first.first
=> "xyz1"
```

or a "dummy" split on string too:

```
[4] pry(main)> "No#xyz1".split("No#")
=> ["", "xyz1"]
[5] pry(main)> "No#xyz1".split("No#").last
=> "xyz1"
```

I would recommend the first one, though.

Comment: Note that both methods fail if `No#` isn't present in the string. I don't know what the desired behaviour is.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-partition) works fine here.

> Searches sep or pattern (regexp) in the string and returns the part
>   before it, the match, and the part after it. If it is not found,
>   returns two empty strings and str.

```
"No#xyz1".partition("No#")
# => ["", "No#", "xyz1"]
"No#xyz1".partition("NotHere")
# => ["No#xyz1", "", ""]
```

So you can use :

```
"No#xyz1".partition("No#").last
# => "xyz1"
```